# For a SplineArea scrolling chart, show minute graduation on x-axis, but plot points every 6 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I'm playing around with the MSChart library, and have created a chart that scrolls on the x-axis when a limit is reached:

```
    foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
    {
            if (series.Points.Count > numberOfPointsInChart + 1)
            {
                series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
                chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Minimum = pointIndex - numberOfPointsInChart - 1;
                chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Maximum = pointIndex;
            }

            series.Points.AddXY(pointIndex, random.Next(0, 50));
    }
```

I now need to convert this to a chart that shows five point on the x-axis for 5 minutes, but the plotted points need to be every 6 seconds. So for every minute-division on the x-axis, 5 points will be plotted, without those plotted points showing as labels on the x-axis.

My question: Is this possible? And if it is could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: To control the 'graduation' as you call it change the Interval on the Axis. To control the labels maybe set their format or use custom labels. To have seconds and minutes set the axis' datatype to datetime with an appropriate datatime.interval!